# Implementing a "virtual" method returning *this (covariant return type)

Tags: c++, this, virtual-functions, self-reference, explicit-object-parameter

I'm writing a hierarchy of classes of C++, let's say `A`, `B` inheriting `A`, `C` inheriting `A`, and `D` inheriting `B`.

Now, all of these classes must have a method `bar() &`, whose body is:

```cpp
{
    A::foo();
    return *this;
}
```

It's the exact same code, doing the exact same thing - except for the type of the return value - which returns an lvalue reference to the class' type.

Now, the signature of this method would be different for every class. But - it's essentially the same method. The thing is, the way things stand, I need to replicate the code for it many times. How can I avoid this code duplication?

I was thinking of writing some mixin with CRTP, but when I get into the details it becomes super-ugly.

Note: For the purposes of this example, `bar()` is only defined for lvalues so as not to get into the question of legitimacy of returning `*this` from an rvalue.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a jerk but what is the value on this? You will increase the complexity of your code with something beyond trivial (as it is now), potentially get a performance hit and gain nothing but save a few lines of code.

Comment: Read up on "covariant return types".

Comment: @einpoklum There is really no benefit to implementing `bar()` in the manner you have described.  Just implement it once in `A`, returning `A&`, and if the caller needs access to the derived class then they can `static_cast`/`dynamic_cast` the return value as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It doesn't make sense to me to: 1. Put burden on the user rather than the library author and 2. Cause massive redundant code instead of limited redundant code.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Ah yes, indeed, exactly the term I should have used.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher: This is not for performance-critical code, so that doesn't matter. I indeed only want to save a few lines of code. If I can't do so with relative ease I'll just live with the duplication :-(

Comment: Today, you'd have to us CRTP. `template<typename Final> struct A { Final& bar() { A::foo(); return static_cast<Final&>(*this); }}; template<typename Final> struct B : A<Final> {}; struct D: B<D>{};` In C++23, you'll be able to use "[deducing this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html)": `struct A { template<typename Self>  Self& bar(this Self& self) { self.foo(); return self;} }; struct B : A{}; struct D : B{};`

Comment: @RaymondChen: 1. That feature is magical. It seems so esoteric at first, then you notice it popping up in more and more cases. 2. I said `A` is a class... a concrete class.

Comment: @einpoklum it would help if you could show an example of how you WANT to use these classes, and then someone can show you how to actually do it, or reject it as not possible.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't understand your complaint about `A`. In the CRTP version, `A` is a concrete template class; in the "deducing this" version, it's a non-template class. (They just happen to use the keyword `struct` to avoid having to type `public` everywhere.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau The obvious use case for this is fluent style code. `D d; d.foo().bar().baz();` If `bar()` returned an `A&`, then you would have to write `static_cast<D&>(d.foo().bar()).baz();` which is no fun at all. You may as well just give up and write `d.foo().bar(); d.baz();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Raymond Chen commented, c++23 would have [deducing this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html) which allows code like:

```
struct A
{
    template <typename Self>
    Self& bar(this Self& self) // Here self is the static type which calls bar
                               // so potentially the derived type
    {
        self.A::foo(); // or self.foo();
        return self;
    }
    // ...
};
struct B : A{};
struct C : A{};
struct D : B{};
```

But currently, CRTP might help, something like:

```
struct A
{
    // ...
};


template <typename Derived, typename Base>
struct A_CRTP : Base
{
    Derived& bar()
    {
        A::foo();
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
    // ...
};
struct B : A_CRTP<B, A> {};
struct C : A_CRTP<C, A> {};
struct D : A_CRTP<D, B> {};
```